# Using .get() within tkinter ScrolledFrame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to achieve grabbing par02_1 using .get(). I have success writing the rest of the .txt file but my program is not grabbing my gui entry lines. I'm guessing this has something to do with the association self, and the scrollable section, etc. but I can't track this one down. Any help is appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import time

root = Tk()

# GUI Window
root.title("Outfile Automation")


# Gui Future Menu Logic
def future01():
    print("Future Command 01")


# GUI Main Menu
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New Script...", command=future01)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit Program", command=future01)

helpMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpMenu, command=future01)
helpMenu.add_command(label="Instruction Manual", command=future01)
helpMenu.add_command(label="Software Version: A0.003")


##Scrollbar

class VerticalScrolledFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)

        # create a canvas object and a vertical scrollbar for scrolling it
        vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT, expand=FALSE)
        canvas = Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                        yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
        canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)
        vscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

        # reset the view
        canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        # create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it
        self.interior = interior = Frame(canvas)
        interior_id = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior,
                                           anchor=NW)

        # track changes to the canvas and frame width and sync them,
        # also updating the scrollbar
        def _configure_interior(event):
            # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
            size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())
            canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
                canvas.config(width=interior.winfo_reqwidth())

        interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)

        def _configure_canvas(event):
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the inner frame's width to fill the canvas
                canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width=canvas.winfo_width())

        canvas.bind('<Configure>', _configure_canvas)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    class AutoApp(Tk):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            root = Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

            self.frame = VerticalScrolledFrame(root)
            self.frame.pack()
            self.label = Label(text="")
            self.label.pack()

            self.par02_1 = StringVar()

            title_1 = Label(self.frame.interior, text="Device IP (DHCP)", fg="blue", font="Verdana 10 underline")
            title_1.pack()
            label_1 = Label(self.frame.interior, text="Device 01")
            label_1.pack()
            entry_1 = Entry(self.frame.interior, textvariable=self.par02_1)
            entry_1.pack()

            outFile = open('CSC.txt', 'wt')
            outFile.write("[Script Header]\nDebugStrings=on\nAbortOnError=on\nConcurrentSectionLimit=230\n"
                          "//23 Devices if necessary""\n\n[Variables]""\n"
                          + (self.par02_1.get()) + "\n\n"
                          "[Device01]\nConnect=tcp |proc01|\nRunAsSingleTransaction=on\nEthernetDHCPHost "
                          + (self.par02_1.get()) + "EthernetCurrentConnectionInfo\n")

            outFile.close()

            def muser():
                feedback_1 = Label(root, text="Creating Script...").pack()
                feedback_2 = Label(root, text="Script Complete!").pack()
                time.sleep(2)
                return

            # GUI Buttons
            mbutton = Button(root, text="Create Script", command=muser, fg="black", bg='green')
            mbutton.pack()


    app = AutoApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're trying to write out the value in the __init__ method - don't do that - your instance isn't even initialized at that point.  Create another method (and a way to call or run it) that will write your file out *after* you've filled in the GUI entries.

Comment: Is there a reason `_configure_canvas` and `_configure_interior` and `muser` are indented an extra level, or is that a mistake when pasting the code?

Comment: Sorry a lot of the work is from other examples online and this is my first program/experience with python so i'm not sure of all the syntax within the file. I know the muser command must be indented to display where I want it to within the gui.

Comment: Are there other commands besides .get() that might be applicable in this situation? I will try utilizing the outFile command later inline after the gui processes but i'm not sure if .get() is the correct call method.

Answer (score 0):

Hello thank you both for your guidance as I learn proper syntax. I have a long way to go but you both helped point me in the right direction so I can get my program online. I stripped this down to the basics and will implement a variation of the following architecture in my actual code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import time

root = Tk()

# GUI Window
root.title("Outfile Automation")


# Gui Future Menu Logic
def future01():
    print("Future Command 01")


# GUI Main Menu
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New Script...", command=future01)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit Program", command=future01)

helpMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpMenu, command=future01)
helpMenu.add_command(label="Instruction Manual", command=future01)
helpMenu.add_command(label="Software Version: A0.003")

par02_1 = StringVar()

title_1 = Label(root, text="Device IP (DHCP)", fg="blue", font="Verdana 10 underline")
title_1.pack()
label_1 = Label(root, text="Device 01")
label_1.pack()
entry_1 = Entry(root, textvariable=par02_1)
entry_1.pack()


root.mainloop()

template = """[Script Header]\nDebugStrings=on\nAbortOnError=on\nConcurrentSectionLimit=230\n//23 Devices if necessary
                \n\n[Variables]\n{}\n\n[Device01]\nConnect=tcp |proc01|\nRunAsSingleTransaction=on\nEthernetDHCPHost\nEthernetCurrentConnectionInfo\n"""


outFile = open('CSC.txt', 'wt')
outFile.write(template.format(par02_1.get()).rstrip())

outFile.close()

root.mainloop()
```